# I am getting a BankAccountRestricted error on line 20 and 32 in Python 3

Tags: class

Here is where I create the class BankAccount on line 1:

Class BankAccount():
   def__init__(self, name):

```
 self.cust_name = name
 self.balance = 0
```

Here is a class calling BankAccount on line 20:

Class BankAccountRestricted(BankAccount):
      def **init**(self, name):
          BankAccount.**init**(self, name)

Line 32 is:

chris = BankAccountRestricted('Christopher Jones')

My error message is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Classes.py", line 20, in 
    class BankAccountRestricted(BankAccount):
  File "Classes.py", line 32, in BankAccountRestricted
    chris = BankAccountRestricted('Christopher Jones')
NameError: name 'BankAccountRestricted' is not defined